# Window orientationchange event in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, orientation-changes, masonry

Is there a way to call the orientationchange event inside an AngularJS directive?

I'm currently working with [angular-masonry](https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry) and I'm trying to update/refresh 
masonry when the orientation of the mobile device changes.

I've found this but I'm wondering how to do this with the $window service inside Angular

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
  // Announce the new orientation number
  console.log(window.orientation);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

```
angular.element($window).bind('orientationchange', function () {

});
```

Comment: Thx, easier than I thought!

Comment: Ofc don't forget to inject $window in your controller !

Comment: But there is something very strange, 'orientationchange" is fire before the screen width change ... So if I execute something just after 'orientationchange' and try to get the new width it doesn't work, give me the old one.

Comment: Don't forget to add $scope.$apply();

Answer (score 6):

Hope this helps. Attach directive as attr, to body. Tested with IPhone 5.

```
'use strict';

angular.module('appModuleNameHere')
    .directive('DirPrefixNameOrientationChange', ['$rootScope',function ($state) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        link: function postLink($scope, element, attrs) {

            element.bind('orientationchange', function () {
                $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
            });

        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: This solution helped me in my map directive. Thx =D

Answer (score 4):

I implemented it this way:

```js
$window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function() {
  your code here
}, false);
```

What do you think?

Comments are welcome.